# Why is does this Toast(Android Studio) works only at the second click

Tags: java, string, android-studio

I have made a `EditText` clickable, and I in the Java class I made this private void:

```
private void incaseofclick() {
            EditText Ct=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.CODIGOnumero);//The EditText
            Ct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.INDICA3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//
                }
            });
    }
```

... The problem is that, in the emulator, I have to press twice(`EditText`) for the toast to work, I want to know why, and how to fix it...
Summarized: What I want is to press it once and the toast and the keyboard(Not a problem) to appear
.

Comment: When does this method get called?

Comment: When the user press the EditText...

Comment: I do not understand why it is strange/unkown that you have to press twice. You have to press at least one to to "install" the `OnClickListener` that shows the `Toast` message. Therefore it cannot do something until this is done. So what magic is necessary to change that? How about "installing" this listener on `Activity` startup?

Comment: This code is executed before or when you click the editText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do it just like this?

```
private void incaseofclick() {

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.INDICA3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: How would the program knows that is referred to the EditText?

Comment: Because you wrote something like "android:onClick="incaseofclick"" in your .xml or set the clicklistener earlier, in your onCreate method for example.